# Percolation in Bethe Lattice with Alternating Neighboor Numbers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, probability, percolation

Suppose we have a [Bethe Lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_lattice) with  alternating numbers of neighbours,starting from 3 and then 4 and so on.
So the zeroth point has 3 neighbours, each of those 3 first neighbours has 4 neighbours (3 new branches comming out of each), each of those 4 has 3 (2 new branches comming out of each), etc. 
[image]

Each point (site) has probability $p$ of being occupied and $1-p$ not occupied. We are interested in the critical probability $p_c$ above which an infite cluster of sites forms with probability 1. Also we're interested in the probability $P(p)$ of an arbitrary point belonging to an  infinite cluster (close the the critical point).

---

### Solution for the simple case Z=3

In the simplest case where we have $Z=3$ neighbours for each point, not alternating, it's quite easy to define as $Q$ the probability that a point is not connected to infinity by one of its branches, thus you'd have: 
$$ P(p)= p(1-Q^3)$$
That's because $p$ is the probability of being occupied, $Q^3$ is the probability that a point is not connected to infinity by all 3 of its branches and $1-Q^3$ is the opposite. Also we can easily see $$ Q=1-p +pQ^2$$

That's the  sum of the probabilites of one of it's neighbours not being occupied ($1-p$), plus the probability that the neighbour IS occupied ($p$) but is not connected to infinity himself ($Q^2$). Then we can find $Q=1$ or $Q=(1-p)/p$ corresponding to $P=0$ and $P=p(1- (\frac{1-p}{p})^3)$. Thus we see that for $p_c = 1/2$ the two solutions for $Q$ become equal to $1$ and $P=0$, the problem is solved.

---

I've tried so far following the same concept to solve the alternating Z problem, starting by defining as $Q_{3}$,$Q_{4}$ the propablity that a point with $3,4$ (respectively) neighbours does not connect to infinity by one of its branches. Then, if I'm not mistaken I'd have $$ Q_3 = 1-p + pQ_4 ^3$$
and $$Q_4= 1-p +pQ_3 ^2 $$

Already it looks very hard to solve for $Q_{3,4}$ and I'm also hesitating as to how I am to express $P(p)$ using those two. Wont I also have to include the probability of my arbitrary point being either with 3 or 4 neighbours (which seems quite hard to calculate as well).

Anyone has an idea on how to continue from here, or wether we should approach it another way? How are we to find $p_c$ and $P(p)$?

Comment: The simplest way to do that is probably to relate this to the survival probability of a Galton-Watson process. Namely each vertex of generation $k$ connected to a vertex of generation $k-1$ is a "child" of the latter. Percolation is then equivalent to non-extinction of the descendants of the original vertex. The critical case is well-known to correspond to the case in which the average number of children is equal to $1$. In your example ($Z=3$ for all vertices), the average number of children is equal to $2p(1-p)+2p^2=2p$, which is equal to $1$ when $p=1/2$.

Comment: Now, in your case where the degrees alternate between two values, just merge two successive generations into a single one. So, each vertex (except the root, which can be analyzed separately) has between $0$ and $6$ "children". The distribution of the number of children is easily found and you then only have to compute the expected number of children.

Comment: By the way, the easiest way to compute the distribution of number of children when you merge two generations is to use generating functions.